# strange text in gmail inbox - php issue?

Tags: php, email, gmail

I have a mailer code which worked fine until a couple days when the received email instead of normal email came as a code to Gmail... like that:

```
--PHP-mixed-a3bf01bb0d28e41880e43720dfc8860d
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary="PHP-alt-a3bf01bb0d28e41880e43720dfc8860d"

--PHP-alt-a3bf01bb0d28e41880e43720dfc8860d
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="iso-8859-1"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

       Type here...

--PHP-alt-a3bf01bb0d28e41880e43720dfc8860d
Content-Type: text/html; charset="iso-8859-1"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

<div style="width:900px"><br /><p>
       Type here...</p>

--PHP-alt-a3bf01bb0d28e41880e43720dfc8860d--

--PHP-mixed-a3bf01bb0d28e41880e43720dfc8860d
Content-Type: ; name=""
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: attachment

--PHP-mixed-a3bf01bb0d28e41880e43720dfc8860d--
```

any idea where to start to track it back. As far as I know I haven't chaned anything on the code at all.

Dummy question but I have no idea where to start... any comment would be welcome and I am willing to learn. Thank you for your time...

update-

Here is the code which produces the code above:

mail.php

```
<?php 
 function csatlakozas($szerver, $user, $pw)
 { // evvel meg csatlakozom az adatbÃ¡zishoz, hogy ki tudjam olvasni a cÃ­mzetteket
 if (!$con = mysql_connect($szerver, $user, $pw))
{
die('Could not connect to SQL DB: ' .mysql_error().'<br/>Try it later AND please report to your system administrator!');
}
};

//belepes a db-be
csatlakozas("localhost","use","pass");
    mysql_select_db("db");

//atveszem a csoport neveket es elszaladok mailozni csoportonkent...
$result=$_POST['to-k'];
$datum=date("Y-m-d");
$subject = $_POST["subject"];
$head="<div style=\"width:900px\"><br />";
$messagetext = $_POST["message"];
$foot="</div>";
$message = $head.$messagetext.$foot;

echo "<p>Original message</p>";
echo $message;

echo "<p>Mass mail has been sending to:</p>";

//kezdodik a csoportok kiolvasasa...
foreach($result as $value)
        { 
    echo "<h3>".$value."</h3>";

    // kiolvasom a cimzetteket az adott kategoriaban
    $sql="SELECT * FROM emails WHERE sendesstat=1 AND deleted=0 AND classhoz=\"".$value."\"";
    //echo $sql;
    $query=mysql_query($sql);

    // kuldjuk az emailokat
    while($data=mysql_fetch_array($query))
        {

        //define the receiver of the email 
        $to = $data["firstname"]." ".$data["surname"]." <".$data["email"].">"; // ******* itt a form adatai
        $from = "my ltd <admin@myweb.co.uk>";  // ******* itt a form adatai
        //create a boundary string. It must be unique 
        //so we use the MD5 algorithm to generate a random hash 
        $random_hash = md5(date('r', time())); 
        //define the headers we want passed. Note that they are separated with \r\n 
        $headers = "From: ".$from."\r\nReply-To: ".$from;  // ******* itt a form adatai 
        //add boundary string and mime type specification 
        $headers .= "\r\nMIME-Version: 1.0\r\nContent-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"PHP-mixed-".$random_hash."\""; 
        //read the atachment file contents into a string,
        //encode it with MIME base64,
        //and split it into smaller chunks
        // ************************************
        // itt kellett belenyúlni
        // ************************************
        $fname=$_FILES["fileatt"]["name"];
        $filename=$_FILES["fileatt"]["tmp_name"];
        $filetype=$_FILES["fileatt"]["type"];
        $attachment=chunk_split(base64_encode(file_get_contents($filename)));
        // ************************************
        // eddig
        // ************************************
        //define the body of the message. 

        include 'sendmail.php';
        }
        }
?>
```

sendmail.php:

```
<?php

 ob_start(); //Turn on output buffering 
?> 
--PHP-mixed-<?php echo $random_hash; ?>  
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary="PHP-alt-<?php echo $random_hash; ?>"

--PHP-alt-<?php echo $random_hash; ?>  
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="iso-8859-1" 
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

<?php echo strip_tags($message); ?>

--PHP-alt-<?php echo $random_hash; ?>  
Content-Type: text/html; charset="iso-8859-1" 
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

<?php echo $message; ?>

--PHP-alt-<?php echo $random_hash; ?>-- 

--PHP-mixed-<?php echo $random_hash; ?>  
Content-Type: <?php echo $filetype;?>; name="<?php echo $fname;?>"  
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64  
Content-Disposition: attachment  

<?php echo $attachment; ?> 
--PHP-mixed-<?php echo $random_hash; ?>-- 

<?php 
//copy current buffer contents into $message variable and delete current output buffer 
$msg = ob_get_clean(); 

//send the email 
//$mail_sent = 0;
$mail_sent = @mail($to, $subject, $msg, $headers, " -f admin@mydomai.co.uk" ); 
//if the message is sent successfully print "Mail sent". Otherwise print "Mail failed" 
echo $mail_sent ? "Mail sent to ".$to."<br />" : "Mail failed to ".$to."<br />"; 
?>
```

I hope there is a good solution as haven't found anything yet on google which would make life easy about this:(

Comment: the question isn't so clear to me but just a note: gmail only accepts email from servers with trusted IPs.

Comment: thanks very much, but I receive the email but with the content above rather than a proper email.

Comment: What does your "mailer code" looks like?

Comment: Hi corubba, I have attached the code not the tydiest but it worked before... but know I am getting just the code instead of the proper email, appreciate your help

Comment: I would give bounty if I could... as well

Comment: Was this just a single message, or something that's happening consistently. Typically this is a problem with improperly formatted headers.

Comment: Dear All, thanks for the comments, I haven't found the solution and my guess the wrong header however I could not spend more time to find out how this would work and changed my script to swift mailer... It is working now and I hope someone some day will find it as a challenge. Thanks again